# Deeplinking an application via an email

Tags: android, deep-linking

Google teaches us the following about how to invoke an android application from the browser [here](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents). In short we are to place a special intent prefix in the href of the  element like so.

```
<a href="intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;end"> Take a QR code </a>
```

However I notice that this doesn't work when the html is emailed. Then only the anchor with http and www as a prefix would be clickable.

Is this by design?. Does that mean we cannot invoke an android application from an email body as of now ?

Comment: That's a chrome intent.  Only chrome uses that.  Everything else uses normal intents-  just put the url, including any custom scheme, directly as the href.

Comment: Also note i fhte user is using any browser other than chrome, your initial code won't work either.  Yeah, I don't know what the hell Google was up to with those chrome intents, they made things a lot harder.

Comment: @Gabe you'd notice that in an email client , anything in the href that isn't a website url isnt clickable.

Comment: Depends on the email client.  You can't assume they all work the same.  Although I would highly recommend using a service that provides deep linking functionality just for this kind of issue.